# Adding MouseMotionListeners

Tags: java, awt, actionlistener, mousemove, mouse-listeners

I currently have an abstract class which extends JComponent. In this class I have defined a method as follows:

```
public void makeMouseOverListener(){
System.out.println("Inside make mouseover...");
MouseMotionListener ret = new MouseMotionListener(){
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

    }
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Mouse Moved");
    }
};
this.addMouseMotionListener(ret);
}
```

I extend this abstract class with a few other objects, and in the constructors of each of those objects I call this method. I always see the first println, but the "Mouse Moved" line never shows up in my console. I also tried directly creating this MouseMotionListener in each constructor, but with the same results. So ultimately my question is, How can I ensure that I get a working motion listener into my objects? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The code inside of the new MouseMotionListener( **code**  ) it seems like this ..
**

```
MouseMotionListener ret = new MouseMotionListener(
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    }
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Mouse Moved");
    }
});
```

**

Answer (score 0):

If you're invoking `makeMouseOverListener` in the constructor of your custom components, then its very likely that the mouse position is never positioned over the component itself. Ensure that the dimension of the component is great than `0 x 0`. This can be achieved by using a layout manager. e.g. position the component at `BorderLayout.CENTER` location.

Comment: That was my initial thought as well. However, I use code similar to        




this.setSize(new Dimension(2* radius, 2 * radius));//set size so the listener has some area to listen to.
this.setLocation(new Point(x-radius, y-radius));

In every constructor, so the component should be the size and position I want it...

Comment: Sounds like youre using `null` layout which is likely the problem. Use  a layout manager instead. Consider posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to give a full picture as to why this isnt working

Comment: I don't think a layout manager would really be feasible in this case, though. I need to position all of my components absolutely because I don't know where they will be until I receive user input.